# How to get values from first column of excel file as array?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Hi I want to get values from first column of excel file as array.

*Already I wrote this code-*

```
import os
import pandas as pd

for file in os.listdir("./python_files"):
    if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
        df = pd.read_excel(os.path.join("./python_files", file))   
        print(df.iloc[:,1])
```

**What i got in output now**

```
0       172081
1       163314
2       173547
3       284221
4       283170
         ...
3582    163304
3583    160560
3584    166961
3585    161098
3586    162499
Name: Organization CRD#, Length: 3587, dtype: int64
```

**What I whish to get**

```
172081
163314
173547
284221
283170
  ...
163304
160560
166961
161098
162499
```

Can somebody help? Thanks :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will just need to use the [tolist](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.tolist.html) function from pandas:

```py
import os
import pandas as pd

for file in os.listdir("./python_files"):
    if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
        df = pd.read_excel(os.path.join("./python_files", file)) 
        print(df.iloc[:,1].tolist())
```

Output

```
172081
163314
173547
284221
283170
  ...
163304
160560
166961
161098
162499
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for :D Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

As an array:

```
df.iloc[:,1].values
```

As a list:

```
df.iloc[:,1].values.tolist()
```